# How do I sort nested list of tuples with letter and number combinations

Tags: python, python-3.x, sorting, nested, tuples

I need to sort my nested list of tuples first on the integer (second element) then on the string/number combination (first element).  I am trying to get the first element to be in ascending order after the second element is sorted.  A good example is the tuples with 2nd element of 10.  d522 should be the first tuple in the group of tens.

Expected output example

```
#[[('d51', 23), ('d874', 20), ('d486', 15), ('d329', 12), ('d1328', 11), ('d1268', 11), ('d114', 11), ('d522', 10),('d717', 10),('d792', 10)]
```

```
tupple=[[('d51', 23), ('d874', 20), ('d486', 15), ('d329', 12), ('d1328', 11), ('d1268', 11), ('d114', 11), ('d792', 10), ('d717', 10),('d522', 10)],
        [('d51', 23), ('d874', 20), ('d486', 15), ('d329', 12), ('d1328', 11), ('d1268', 11)]]

for item in tupple:
    sorted(item, key=lambda element: (element[1], (int("".join([i for i in element[0] if i.isdigit()])))),reverse=True)
# new = [[item[0] for item in inner] for inner in tupple]
tupple

###output  [[('d51', 23),  ('d874', 20),  ('d486', 15),  ('d329', 12),  ('d1328', 11), ('d1268', 11),  ('d114', 11),  ('d792', 10),  ('d717', 10),  ('d522', 10)], [('d51', 23),  ('d874', 20),  ('d486', 15),  ('d329', 12),  ('d1328', 11),  ('d1268', 11)]]
```

Comment: Thus, an outer sort on the second element in descending order, and then an inner sort (for equal second elements) in ascending order by the first element, ignoring the string part of the first element?

Comment: @9769953 Yes 
I thought the join would handle that and then read the digit  Do I need some type of split?

Comment: The join + int conversion was not the problem. You never assigned the result back, and while tupple and its elements are mutable, `sorted()` will return a copy. So the final result was just the input `tupple`. `item.sort(...)` would have worked, except that you then still had the outer-descending / inner-ascending problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can force the second part of the key to be the other way around. In this case, that is fairly easy: just put a minus sign in front of the created number, and the (secondary) comparison is inverted.

(You also forgot to assign the result of `sorted()` back to `tupple[i]`, since `sorted()` returns a copy; it doesn't alter `item` in place, in contrast to `item.sort()`. But I find `tupple[i] = sorted(...)` clearer here.

```
tupple=[[('d51', 23), ('d874', 20), ('d486', 15), ('d329', 12), ('d1328', 11), ('d1268', 11), ('d114', 11), ('d792', 10), ('d717', 10),('d522', 10)],
        [('d51', 23), ('d874', 20), ('d486', 15), ('d329', 12), ('d1328', 11), ('d1268', 11)]]

for i, item in enumerate(tupple):
    tupple[i] = sorted(item, key=lambda element: (element[1], -int("".join(i for i in element[0] if i.isdigit()))), reverse=True)
    # Or alternatively
    # item.sort(key=lambda element: (element[1], -int("".join(i for i in element[0] if i.isdigit()))), reverse=True)
tupple
```

which results in

```
[[('d51', 23), ('d874', 20), ('d486', 15), ('d329', 12), ('d114', 11), 
('d1268', 11), ('d1328', 11), ('d522', 10), ('d717', 10), ('d792', 10)], 
[('d51', 23), ('d874', 20), ('d486', 15), ('d329', 12), ('d1268', 11), ('d1328', 11)]]
```